# MS SQL выдаёт ошибку на блоке WHERE

Tags: sql-server

Доброго времени суток, пишу простенький триггер в MS SQL и выдаёт ошибку в блоке WHERE object_name = @name_device т.к. строку он не может без кавычек сравнить.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER tcontrolpuskdev
ON  [dbo].[tcontrol] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
  DECLARE @pusk1 int(1), @name_device varchar(6);
  SET @pusk1 = (SELECT TOP(1) Puskatel1 from instered)
  SET @name_device = (SELECT TOP(1)Puscatel1 FROM INSERTED)
  UPDATE devices
  SET pusk1_dev = @pusk1 WHERE object_name = @name_device
GO
```

Вот сам текст ошибки:

> Msg 2716, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tcontrolpuskdev, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot specify a column width on data type int.

Подскажите совет пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В MS SQL Server у int нельзя задавать размер. Замените `int(1)` на `int`.

Comment: Скорее на `decimal(1)`?

Comment: @Qwertiy на самом деле лучше заменить на тот тип, который задан у колонки Puskatel1 в tcontrol (главное не перепутать с Puscatel1)

Comment: @PashaPash Посмотрел более внимательным взглядом на сиё творение и вместо Puscatel1, нужно поставить object_name и вместо instered - > inserted. В итоге ошибок по синтаксису нет. Но при запуске выдает некорректное имя в CREATE TRIGGER